# How to change column names of a dataframe using rpy2

Tags: r, dataframe, rpy2

I want to do the equivalent of this R code:

```
m2 <- cbind(1,2)
colnames(m2) <- c("x","Y")
```

When I do

```
import rpy2.robjects as R
m2 = R.r['cbind'](1,2)
R.r['colnames'](m2) = R.StrVector(['x','y'])
```

I get this error:

```
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

I tried

```
>>> m2 = R.r['colnames'](m2, R.StrVector(['x','y']))
>>> print m2

[1] "x1" "y2"
```

And

```
>>> params = {'do.NULL':False}
>>> m2 = R.r['colnames'](R.StrVector(['x','y']), m2, **params)
>>> print m2

[1] "11" "21"
```

Which both don't give the result that I want. So how can I use colnames to change the column names of a dataframe?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If anyone wants to know, the answer is:

```
m2.colnames = R.StrVector(['x','y'])
```

Comment: Great post! This is very valuable info for rPy2 users.